# Track buffer changes and trigger a hook after event in Emacs

Tags: matlab, emacs, elisp

I'm trying to add some facilities to my matlab environment within Emacs.
Basically, I want to have an extra buffer (*Matlab Whos*) to display all my variables. The buffer should update automatically *after* matlab-shell finishes evaluating an expression. In other words, *after* I press return on the shell, a hook should call a function to update *Matlab Whos*.

The simple solution I came up with is:

```
(defvar matlab-whos-buffer-name "*Matlab Whos*")

(defun matlab-whos-buffer-update ()
 "Create Matlab Whos buffer if it doesn't exist. 
 If it exists, update its values."
  (lambda)
  (interactive)
  (let ((doc-whos (matlab-shell-collect-command-output "whos")))
    (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create matlab-whos-buffer-name)
      (erase-buffer)
      (insert doc-whos))))

(add-hook 'matlab-shell-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (define-key matlab-shell-mode-map (kbd "<return>")
              (lambda ()
                (interactive)
                (comint-send-input)
                (matlab-whos-buffer-update)))))
```

The function `matlab-whos-buffer-update` works fine. However, the problem with this solution is that my hook calls the function before the matlab shell finishes its evaluation (requested by `(comint-send-input)`). As a consequence, `matlab-whos-buffer-update` returns an error saying:

> Matlab-shell-collect-command-output: MATLAB shell must be non-busy to
>   do that.

How can I track changes to my Matlab shell buffer, so that my hook knows that it can only trigger `matlab-whos-buffer-update`, after the result of the evaluation has returned?

Comment: Have you tried using `comint-output-filter-functions`?

Comment: How does one use that properly? I just tried `(add-hook 'matlab-shell-mode-hook '(cons 'matlab-whos-buffer-update 'comint-output-filter-functions)` , but that also didn't work. (Nothing happened)

Comment: General comment: add one function to a hook at a time, like `(add-hook 'foo-hook 'foo-func)`.  It's fine in your question but not your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with something like

```
(add-hook 'matlab-shell-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (add-hook 'comint-output-filter-functions
                      #'matlab-whos-buffer-update
                      nil 'local)))
```

But note that this will call your function everytime something is sent from the process.  I can foresee two problems with it:

- it may fail miserably if `matlab-shell-collect-command-output` ends up using that same setup (and hence also calling `matlab-whos-buffer-update`.
- it might be run too many times (if your process sends its output in 5 chunks, it will be run 5 times).

Try it and come back with another question if that doesn't work well enough.